# I am getting some issues regarding retrieving data from ms access database

Tags: java, resultset, ms-access-2013, ucanaccess

I am trying to retrieve data from database but i am getting some issues.
Here is my code:

```
  {
        try
         {
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://F:\\Realestate\\real estate.accdb");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
String sql="select Property type,Property owner from property where Property type='"+searchbyidfld.getText()+"'and Property owner='"+searchbynamefld.getText()+"'";
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
if(rs.next())
{
  String retrieve=rs.getString("Property type");
  System.out.println(retrieve);
 }
  }
catch(Exception ex)
 {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No record found");                                           
   }
   }
```

I also provided right path of the database in the URL.
Here is my database from where i am trying to retrieve data[image] 
I don't know what i am doing wrong.

here is the stack trace:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 user lacks privilege or object not found: PROPERTY
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 user lacks privilege or object not found: PROPERTY
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:211)
    at real.estate.Loginbtn$4$27$9$11.actionPerformed(Loginbtn.java:1691)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
```

Comment: "but i am getting some issues" -- what issues are you getting. Be specific. Is it an exception? What's the stacktrace? Which line is it in your source code? People are not going to run your code to find - which would be hard anyway as we don't have your database schema.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt no it's not giving me any exception

Comment: Column names that contain spaces must be enclosed in square brackets, e.g., `select [Property type], [Property owner] from property ...`

Comment: Then what issue ***are*** you getting?

Comment: would you please see my stack trace,i have updated my question

Comment: Your code is also vulnerable to *SQL injection* problems. (Imagine what will happen if [property owner] is `Sally O'Malley`.) You should be using a `PreparedStatement` to execute a *parameterized query*.

Comment: *Column names that contain spaces must be enclosed in square brackets*: or much better, they shouldn't contain spaces in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in your code `String sql="select [Property type],[Property owner] from property where [Property type]='"+searchbyidfld.getText()+"'and [Property owner]='"+searchbynamefld.getText()+"'";`
column names containing spaces should be enclosed in square brackets.I hope this will work fine for you